# How do I check for variation of a distribution over spatial scales?

Tags: distributions, data-visualization, inference, spatial

I have about 30000 particles distributed (not randomly) in space; I have their vector positions and velocities.
I'm trying to characterize if and how the (underlying) velocity (magnitude) distribution these particles are assumed to sample changes on different scales.
The underlying velocity distribution is of unknown form.
Note: My real interest is in the distribution on a scale that I have near zero particles; so I'd like to be able to get a sense of how the scale effects the distributions generally.

I can of course look at distributions made from subsets of nearby points; to my eye these look pretty similar near the edges and very discrepant in the centers. I'd like a way to quantify and visualize this change across scales.

I'm fairly new to statistics so any/all references are welcome. Feel free to suggest/add tags.